# Renaming files works, but soft links point to the old names. How can I fix that?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

For example, I'm renaming many files inside a tree like this:

```
[bash]$ for file in `find . -name "*gsf*"`; do `mv $file ${file/gsf/msf}`; done
```

That renames all the instances of "gsf" in file names matching *gsf* to "msf", but softlinks continue to point to now-non-existent files containing "gsf".

For example, this is what happens after the rename:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 trusktr users     20 Apr 25 14:39 libmsf-1.so -> libgsf-1.so.114.0.23
lrwxrwxrwx 1 trusktr users     20 Apr 25 14:39 libmsf-1.so.114 -> libgsf-1.so.114.0.23
-rwxr-xr-x 1 trusktr users 265584 Apr 21 04:41 libmsf-1.so.114.0.23
```

As you can see, the soft links point to `libgsf-1.so.114.0.23` which doesn't exist anymore because it was renamed to `libmsf-1.so.114.0.23`.

What can I do so that the rename also happens to the soft link pointers?

Comment: Off topic: I wonder if it wouldn't be more efficient to simply use `-exec` option of file, instead of the loop.

Comment: I tried using -exec but couldn't get it to work all in 'one' line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @C2H5OH's and @user1277476's answers, I came up with a solution:

```
$ for file in `find . -type l`; do link=$(readlink $file); ln -sfT ${link//gsf/msf} $file; done
```

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the technical explanation, already answered.  You can change where the symbolic links point to:

1. Find them with `find . -type l`
2. Change their target with `ln -sfT target link_name`

The options `-sfT` must be specified to *repoint* symbolic links without surprises.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing; that's what makes them symbolic links, you need to deal with them yourself.  Hard links reference the actual index node ("inode") in the filesystem, and will therefore remain valid; this is exactly why you would use hard instead of symbolic links in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`find` and `ln` are good.
`readlink` is also good.

Answer (score 2):

Since I cannot add a comment, here is a version which does not invoke a shell for finding links, thus preventing additional overhead due to fork() and other syscalls

```
for file in $(find . -type l); do 
    link=$(readlink $file); 
    ln -sfT ${link//gsf/msf} $file; 
done
```

This is based on @trusktr answer